# TypeError: wrapper() missing 1 required positional argument: 'backend' happens while trying to do Oauth2 login

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

this is my views.py

```
@api_view(http_method_names=['POST']) 
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
@psa()

def exchange_token(request, backend): 
    serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        user = request.backend.do_auth(serializer.validated_data['access_token'])

        if user:#drf built in token authentication??
            token, _ = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user) # drf token authentication
            return Response({'token':token.key})
        else:
            return Response(
                {'errors':{'token':'Invalid token'}},
                status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            )
```

https://www.toptal.com/django/integrate-oauth-2-into-django-drf-back-end
I'm following this page and trying to request using postman
But above error happends.
I think I should pass "backend" argument when requesting, but I don't know what to do right now...

someone please tell me how can I solve this problem

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/park/miniconda3/envs/wantu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/home/park/miniconda3/envs/wantu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/park/miniconda3/envs/wantu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/park/miniconda3/envs/wantu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 84, in view
return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/park/miniconda3/envs/wantu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
response = self.handle_exception(exc)
File "/home/park/miniconda3/envs/wantu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
File "/home/park/miniconda3/envs/wantu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
raise exc
File "/home/park/miniconda3/envs/wantu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/park/miniconda3/envs/wantu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/decorators.py", line 50, in handler
return func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: wrapper() missing 1 required positional argument: 'backend'
```

full traceback error is here

it is my root urls.py
from django.urls import path, include

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("users", include("users.urls")),
    path('applications', include('applications.urls')),
    path("jobs", include("jobs.urls")),
    path('cv', include('cv.urls'))
]
```

and users.urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("/kakao/login", views.exchange_token),
]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: which version of the rest-framework are you using?

Comment: it's djangorestframework==3.13.1

Comment: Please show us your URL definition for this view - it looks like you have failed to include a `backend` parameter in the path definition.

Comment: I'm trying to give backend parameter as query & path variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URL configuration is wrong - it's missing a `backend` named parameter. See [this](https://github.com/coriolinus/oauth2-article/blob/master/views.py#L38), from the code of the tutorial you are referring to:

> The URL at which this view lives must include a backend field, like:
>
> ```
>  url(API_ROOT + r'social/(?P<backend>[^/]+)/$', exchange_token),
> ```

In your case, you need to add the `backend` parameter to the URL:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("/kakao/login/<str:backend>/", views.exchange_token),
]
```

Comment: how can I request "backend" parameter?? 
I'm trying to request via /users/kakao/login/Kakao and 
    return BACKENDSCACHE[name]
KeyError: 'Kakao'
this error happens, I'm finding definition using F12 but can't get a grasp...
sorry for ignorance

Comment: The backend has to be one defined in the `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`. You may need to spend a  bit more time with the sample code from that tutorial to understand how it all fits together.